# converting dictionary within a list to JSON format using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a dictionary within a list as below

```
b = [
    {
        "ServiceLevel": {
            "S": "AA"
        },
        "ReadyTime": {
            "S": "2020-01-31T12:00:00"
        },
        "DeliveryDate": {
            "S": "2020-02-15T12:00:00"
        }
    }
]
```

I am trying to access the elements within that inner dictionary and convert them to JSON format:
My try:

```
a = b[0]
for key, value in sorted(a.items()):
    a1 = print(key, value)

for i in a1:
    b1 = a1[i]
    print(b1)
```

I am trying to get this output:

```
b = {   
        "ServiceLevel": "AA",
        "ReadyTime": "2020-01-31T12:00:00",
        "ReadyDate": "2020-01-31T12:00:00",    
}
```

ERROR : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: What Python version are you using? That error message looks wrong.

Comment: python 3.7 @ superb rain

Comment: Hmm, I just tried 3.7.8 and got "... not iterable" as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning print() method to a variable, here is the NoneType error

```
a1 = print(key, value) # variable a1 is NoneType
for i in a1: # error because variable a1 is not iterable
```

Use :

```
b1 = {}
for key, value in b[0].items():
    b1[key] = value['S']
print(b1)
```

Comment: I am a beginner in python programming and I was not aware of using values['S']. I stored it in print and thought I could iterate over the elements in that print statement. I tried your answer and it is working as expected. Thanks